# Клонирование задания печати C#

Tags: c#

Вопрос в следующем: мне нужно реализовать на C# решение, позволяющее печатать на 2 принтера одновременно (один из них установлен по умолчанию и еще любой из выбранных, установленных в системе). Все задачи должны проходить через очереди печати.
По хорошему, нужно писать драйвер виртуального принтера, но быстро я этого не сделаю.
Я хотел сделать следующее: сохранять файлы Spooler во время печати на принтере по умолчанию и отправлять их на печать на другой принтер. Но сейчас думаю что это не очень хорошая идея, т.к. принтеры могут быть разные. Если кто-то подскажет идею, как это можно сделать, буду признателен!

Comment: добавьте информации в вопрос, не понятно как именно вы пытаетесь решать проблему и как именно её нужно решить

Comment: `PrintQueue` не смотрели?